# Where is Publishing State for a product in Google in-App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Based on google documentation on this link http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-catalog they said a product has a "Publishing State" as

```
Publishing State

An item's publishing state can be Published or Unpublished . To be visible to a user during checkout, an item's publishing state must be set to Published and the item's application must be published on Google Play.

Note: This is not true for test accounts. An item is visible to a test account if the application is not published and the item is published. See Testing In-app Billing for more information.
```

But I cant see that in my product list. There is only a state as "Active"/"Inactive" , are these the Publishing State?

[image]

Comment: i guess, this is because the design of google play developer console is updated but the documentation has not been updated yet.